# How can I change the underline color of MaterialUI's React Tabs component?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui, underline

I noticed there is no documentation on MaterialUI's website in regard to changing the underline color of their Tabs component...

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This property can be changed with the inkBarStyle props:

```
<Tabs inkBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#e77600'}}>
   <Tab label='Tab 1'/>
   <Tab label='Tab 2'/>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `TabIndicatorProps` property to change the underline color.

```
<Tabs TabIndicatorProps={{style: {backgroundColor: "white"}}}>
   <Tab label='Tab 1'/>
   <Tab label='Tab 2'/>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure this in MUI v5 by overriding the style in your custom theme, you can use this:

```
MuiTabs: {
  defaultProps: {
    TabIndicatorProps: { style: { backgroundColor: '#e77600' } },
  },
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<Tabs indicatorColor="white">
   <Tab label="Tab 1"/>
   <Tab label="Tab 2"/>
</Tabs>
```

Indicator Color can take any color  e.g white, red, green e.t.c

Answer (score -2):

In the latest material ui version `v4.9.11`, you need to use indicator props to apply underline color

```
<Tabs indicator={{backgroundColor: '#e77600'}}>
   <Tab label='Tab 1'/>
   <Tab label='Tab 2'/>
</Tabs>
```