# MaterialUI React Tabs Underline Thickness

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

How can I change the underline line thickness of a Material Tab in React? Trying to modify code below.

[How can I change the underline color of MaterialUI's React Tabs component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466011/how-can-i-change-the-underline-color-of-materialuis-react-tabs-component)

```
<Tabs TabIndicatorProps={{style: {backgroundColor: "white"}}}>
   <Tab label='Tab 1'/>
   <Tab label='Tab 2'/>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `height: <value_in_pixel>` to the `style` prop of `TabIndicatorProps` like this:

```js
<Tabs TabIndicatorProps={{style: {backgroundColor: "white", height: 20}}}>
   <Tab label='Tab 1'/>
   <Tab label='Tab 2'/>
</Tabs>
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-tab-underline?file=src%2FApp.jsx) for a live working example of this solution.